# Are packages downloaded from multiple mirror sites?

Tags: fedora, package-management, software-installation, yum, repository

I'm running F17 and inside of `yum.repos.d`. I see multiple repos listed like `adobe-linux-1386.repo`, `fedora.repo`, `google-chrome.repo`, etc. When I `yum install` are some files being downloaded from multiple different repos or all from one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the repositories specify a `mirrorlist` in their configuration file. When present, `yum` will select one or more of the mirrors provided by the list. Repos that don't have mirrors will have `baseurl` instead of `mirrorlist`.

When downloading multiple packages, yum can download from multiple sites in parallel, though this isn't always obvious in the terminal unless you watch very carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Most packages would be downloaded from fedora.repo.  Adobe packages would be downloaded from adobe-linux-i386.repo.  Google Chrome packages would be downloaded from google-chrome.repo

Comment: Can I add repos to this directory?

Comment: If you have root privileges, you can add repos to `/etc/yum.repos.d`

Answer (score 0):

Also depends on whether a repo is disabled or enabled.

Comment: What determines whether a repo is disabled or enabled?

Comment: 2 things that determine whether a repos is enabled or disabled.  (1) the enabled=? line in the repo file (in `/etc/yum.repos.d` (2) Using the `--enablerepo` or `--disablerepo` tag in the yum command.  For example, you could add `enable=0` to your google-chrome.repo.  Then in ordinary operation, yum would ignore google-chrome-repo.  On those occasions when you want google-chrome-repo, do `yum --enable-repo google-chrome.repo ...`

Answer (score 0):

Normally the contents of repository do not have the same rpms (like in your example). If you had "conflicting" rpms you can use yum_priorities to choose which one to use first.

But in the end a single rpm will be downloaded from a single (mirror)-server that is mentioned in a single repository (directly or via mirror-list).